# Change of value of variable in unittest python

Tags: python, python-2.7, unit-testing, python-unittest, nose

```
import unittest

class TestTemplate(unittest.TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(self):
        self.result = 'error'
        print "setUpClass"

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(self):
        print "The value of result is, ",self.result
        if self.result == 'ok':
            print "it is working"
        print "The value of cls result is : ", self.result
        print "TearDownClass"


class MyTest(TestTemplate):

    def test_method_one(self):
        self.result = 'ok'
        print self.result


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

In the `tearDownClass` the value of self.result is `error`, but rather it should be `okay` because I changed it in the method? Is there any resolve to this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are changing a *class attribute* in the `setUp` method, and reading it again in the `tearDown`, because both are class methods. In your test however, you are setting an *instance* attribute.

You'd have to set it on the class directly instead:

```
type(self).result = 'ok'
```

or

```
MyTest.result = 'ok'
```

The latter ties it to the current test class, the first option lets it work even in subclasses.

Demo:

```
>>> import unittest
>>> class TestTemplate(unittest.TestCase):
...     @classmethod
...     def setUpClass(self):
...         self.result = 'error'
...         print "setUpClass"
...     @classmethod
...     def tearDownClass(self):
...         print "The value of result is, ",self.result
...         if self.result == 'ok':
...             print "it is working"
...         print "The value of cls result is : ", self.result
...         print "TearDownClass"
...
>>> class MyTest(TestTemplate):
...     def test_method_one(self):
...         type(self).result = 'ok'
...         print self.result
...
>>> unittest.main(exit=False)
setUpClass
ok
.The value of result is,  ok
it is working
The value of cls result is :  ok
TearDownClass

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

OK
<unittest.main.TestProgram object at 0x103945090>
```

However, you generally want to avoid changing the test class state during individual tests. Use the existing [test runner facilities](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestResult) to track test results instead; all

The `setUpClass` and `tearDownClass` methods *can* apply to multiple tests (depending on how the tests are run), so the state is shared.

Comment: Makes a lot of sense. But is it a good practice in python to change test class state? I am trying to store the the result of each test, whether it has passed or failed.@Martjin Pieters

Comment: @HarshdeepSingh: class state is just as dynamic as instance state; if you need to share state between instances then doing so on the class is fine. Why do you need to store the result of each test on the test class however? The test runner already tracks the state for you.

Comment: @HarshdeepSingh you should examine https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestResult as Martijn says instead of trying to collect results on your own.

Comment: I didn't down vote him, but yes I can use `wasSuccessful`, I will give it a try, thanks!

Comment: @MartijnPieters `wasSuccessful` works when `class methods` are not used, so when `setUp` and `tearDown` is used, can't they work with `setUpClass` and `tearDownClass`?

Comment: Anyways solved it, did the same mistake again thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `self.__class__.result = "ok"`.

The reason it doesn't work is that `setUpClass()` is a *class* method (because of the `@classmethod` decorator), so the `self` parameter there is actually a class. Thus `self.result = 'error'` changes the class attribute.

Comment: `type(self)` is preferable over `self.__class__`, generally. Only use `self.__class__` for old-style Python classes.